# Hosting Vite App with Amplify with different Backend URLs

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, vite, aws-amplify

I have built a frontend application with Vite.
This application is on GitLab in a "`development`" and "`main`" branch.

- In the "`development`" variant, I access the backend `backend-dev.domain.com` multiple times.
- However, in the "`main`" variant, it is `backend.domain.com`.

I have hosted the app via AWS Amplify so that I can now access my app from the "`development`" branch via `app-dev.domain.com` and from the "`main`" branch via `app.domain.com`.
How can I now ensure that the correct backend URL is used when I call up my respective app?

How can I replace the correct URL in the build settings in AWS Amplify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two branches in GitLab each connected to [AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/) for continuous deployment.
The application from the "`main`" branch gets deployed to `app.domain.com` and from the "`development`" branch to `app-dev.domain.com`.
Each of these front-end deployments needs to interact with a different backend URL.

One standard approach to handle different backend URLs for different environments is to use **environment variables**.
That way, you can easily switch between different backend URLs based on the environment (development, staging, production, etc.) your app is running in.

Define [environment variables in AWS Amplify](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html) for each branch/environment. You can see that approach in [step 2.c of Amplify's "Getting started with existing code" example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/getting-started.html#step-2c-add-environment-variables-optional).

In your [Vite app, access these environment variables](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html) to determine the backend URL.

```bash
# AWS Amplify Console
# Under App settings > Environment variables, add your backend URLs:
# For main branch:
BACKEND_URL="https://backend.domain.com"
# For development branch:
BACKEND_URL="https://backend-dev.domain.com"
```

In your Vite app:

```js
// Assuming your code interacts with the backend URL in a file named api.js

// src/api.js
const backendUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL;  // Using environment variable

// Function to fetch data from the backend
async function fetchData(endpoint) {
  const response = await fetch(`${backendUrl}/${endpoint}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

// Rest of your code
```

You get:

```bash
+------------+       +--------------------+       +--------------------+
|   GitLab   |       |   AWS Amplify      |       |   Frontend App    |
|            |       |                    |       |                   |
| +--------+ |       | +--------------+   |       | +--------------+  |
| |"main"  | |       | | Environment  |   |       | |  Access Env  |  |
| |branch  | |       | | Variables    |   |       | |  Vars in     |  |
| +--------+ |       | | BACKEND_URL  |   |       | |  Code        |  |
|            |       | | = backend... |   |       | |              |  |
| +--------+ |       | +--------------+   |       | +--------------+  |
| |"dev"   | |       |                    |       |                   |
| |branch  |-------->| +--------------+   |       | +--------------+  |
| +--------+ | Deploy| | Environment  |   |       | |  Access Env  |  |
+------------+       | | Variables    |   |       | |  Vars in     |  |
                     | | BACKEND_URL  |   |       | |  Code        |  |
                     | | = backend-   |   |       | |              |  |
                     | |   dev...     |---------->| +--------------+  |
                     | +--------------+   |       +---------+----------+
                     +--------------------|                 |
                                                            | Use backendUrl
                                                            |
                             +----------------------+       |
                             |   Backend Server(s)  |<-------
                             |                      |
                             | +------------------+ |
                             | | backend.domain.  | |
                             | | com              | |
                             | +------------------+ |
                             |                      |
                             | +------------------+ |
                             | | backend-dev.     | |
                             | | domain.com       | |
                             | +------------------+ |
                             +----------------------+
```